# Problem parsing data from a firewall log and finding "worm"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling with trying to see what is wrong with my code. I am new to python.

```
import os

uniqueWorms = set()
logLineList = []

with open("redhat.txt", 'r') as logFile:
    for eachLine in logFile:
        logLineList.append(eachLine.split())
    for eachColumn in logLineList:
        if 'worm' in eachColumn.lower():
            uniqueWorms.append()
            print (uniqueWorms)
```

Answer (score 0):

`eachLine.split()` returns a list of words. When you append this to `logLineList`, it becomes a 2-dimensional list of lists.

Then when you iterate over it, `eachColumn` is a list, not a single column.

If you want `logLineList` to be a list of words, use

```
logLineList += eachLine.split()
```

instead of

```
logLineList.append(eachLine.split())
```

Finally, `uniqueWorms.append()` should be `uniqueWOrms.append(eachColumn)`. And `print(uniqueWorms)` should be outside the loop, so you just see the final result, not every time a worm is added.